# Как посмотреть документацию по Pygame и когда сайт станет онлайн?

Tags: python, pygame

На сайте висит только текст '☮ 
In solidarity with NZ Aotearoa we are offline today.'
Можно хоть как-нибудь документацию посмотреть? У меня курс часто на документацию ссылается, а я не могу посмотреть и обучение в частичном тупике

Comment: На сайте слева в самом низу есть ссылка на github, в исходниках можно посмотреть документацию.

Comment: @Муса Дульмиев, я сильно изменил свой ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: я сюда попал когда искал ответ почему pygame не устанавливается. оказалось он не работает пока с python 3.11. но если написать в терминале `pip install pygame --pre`, то установится предварительная версия модуля. Оставлю это тут, вдруг кто-то из новичков моим маршрутом пойдет

Comment: Сайт pygame вполне доступен через vpn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эта программа откроет в браузере начальную страницу документации по PyGame:

```py
import os
import pygame
import webbrowser


def get_parent_dir(path):
    return os.path.sep.join(path.split(os.path.sep)[:-1])


webbrowser.open(f'{get_parent_dir(pygame.__file__)}{os.path.sep}docs{os.path.sep}generated{os.path.sep}index.html')
```

Некоторые ссылки могут не работать, но в целом **документация** работает.

Протестировано на следующем ПО:

- Windows10:

  - Python 3.7 и 3.10:

    - PyGame 2.1 и 2.2
  - Python 3.11:

    - PyGame 2.2
- Linux Mint:

  - Python 3.11 и 3.12:

    - PyGame 2.5

Comment: Если устанавливали в ide, то путь может отличаться file:///C:/Users/...../PycharmProjects/pygame1/venv/Lib/site-packages/pygame/docs/generated/index.html

Answer (score -1):

Можно гораздо проще, просто введите в терминале:

```sh
python -m pygame.docs
```

UPD: На Windows не работает, на Linux отлично.

Comment: У меня не работает. В Microsoft Edge открывается сайт ovgorskiy.ru, а не документация к pygame

Comment: Да в Windows это не совсем работает. Из-за Microsoft Edge и Internet Explorer.

Comment: @DulmievMusa `ovgorskiy.ru` - это как бы немного палит вашу пиратскую сборку Windows) Этот овгорский домашней страницей при установке винды прописался)